# magento: transactional email not sending This letter cannot be sent.

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

I created one transactional email and assigned it to my custom module.
But it throws the

```
     This letter cannot be sent.
```

Error. Debug it and found that email subject getting null in below function.

```
     app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
     /**
      * Return true if this template can be used for sending queue as main template
      *
      * @return boolean
      */
      public function isValidForSend()
      {
           return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
                  && $this->getSenderName()
                  && $this->getSenderEmail()
                  && $this->getTemplateSubject();
      }
```

Is there any missing in creating template?

Also checked that

```
      Mail sending settings set to no
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you try to load this email template in transectional email in admin.

Comment: So, you just need to check 4 conditions - 'system/smtp/disable' setting, sender name, sender email and template subject...

Comment: Dhiren - Yes but result is nothing. Template not loaded. We have two store view one is in English and other is in German. I added same template in both dir. like `app/locale/de_DE/template/email/MODULENAME/test.html` and `app/locale/en_US/template/email/MODULENAME/test.html`

Comment: Roman -  I checked that and found that template subject always null. Any idea?